# CSS column content is disappearing behind footer

Tags: html, css, footer, breakpoints

I am making a basic responsive website for Uni. I am just kind of laying a foundation today as I have about 7 weeks to complete this but I have hit my first roadblock.

Eventually I will need to use CSS grid layout on this site for images so I thought I would test it out just using CSS columns for now until I know how to grid :)

Long story short, the contents of my columns is going behind the footer and for the last hour, I've tried all sorts with no luck I think I know where the problem is I just dont know how to fix it. For some reason as soon as I open up my tags for the columns the body immediately ends.

Also the Center html tags will be removed eventually but I'm struggling with the CSS atm I have this feeling I need a wrapper to put around all the content?

It all looks a little ugly atm, the jQuery class is where a slideshow will go eventually, just an image in there for now.

Thanks

```css
.headerLogo {
 max-width: 300px;
 display:block;
  margin: auto;
}

.jQuery {

margin-bottom: 10px;
min-width: 300px;
display:block;

}

.spacer {
background-color: #a9a9a9;
width:100%;
height:5px;
}

.menu {
width:100%;

background-color: black;
border: 2px;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
}

li {
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 25px;
display: inline;
background-color: #a9a9a9;
color:white;
padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
border: 2px solid #F15A24;
border-radius: 5px;

}

li a:hover {

color: white;
}

a:link, a:visited {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
text-align: center;
padding:0px;
display:inline;
width: 80px;
overflow: hidden;
}

hr {
padding: 20px;
 }

footer {
width:100%;
height: 20%;
background-color: gray;
display:block;
}


 body {
  min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
margin: 0;
background: linear-gradient(#a9a9a9, white);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

[class*='col-']
{
float:left;
display: grid;


}

.col-1-3 {
width: 33%;
max-height: 70%;
position:relative;
}



p {

 }

.container {

}

.footer {

bottom: 0;
left:0;
position:fixed;
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 10%;
width: 100%;
border-top: 5px solid #F15A24 ;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
.jQuery {
visibility:hidden;
 }
li{font-size: 15px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name = "viewport" content= "width=device-width">
  <meta name = "description" decription = "Responsive Web Design">
  <meta name = "keywords" content = "web design, mobile website, affordable 
  design, professional website">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>

      <div>

        <img class = "headerLogo" src="img/Logo1.png"  >

    </div>
    </header>

    <center>
    <nav>
       <ul>

         <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
         <li><a href="gallery.html">Portfolio</a></li>

       </ul>
     </nav>

    <img class = "jQuery" src = "img/iphone.png">

   </center>

  <div class = "grid">
   <div class = "col-1-3">
     <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mattis 
  ultrices sem vitae suscipit. Donec sollicitudin lacus ac nisl fermentum 
  eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et 
  malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur leo leo, aliquet at varius nec, 
  laoreet efficitur ligula. Fusce at lacinia tortor. Interdum et malesuada 
  fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus scelerisque justo id 
  interdum placerat. Aenean tincidunt tellus ac eros viverra rhoncus. Nam 
  vitae sollicitudin magna. Praesent neque tellus, hendrerit et fermentum a, 
  sagittis at lorem. Proin at pellentesque massa. Suspendisse potenti.
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class = "col-1-3">
     <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mattis 
  ultrices sem vitae suscipit. Donec sollicitudin lacus ac nisl fermentum 
  eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et 
  malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur leo leo, aliquet at varius nec, 
  laoreet efficitur ligula. Fusce at lacinia tortor. Interdum et malesuada 
  fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus scelerisque justo id 
  interdum placerat. Aenean tincidunt tellus ac eros viverra rhoncus. Nam 
  vitae sollicitudin magna. Praesent neque tellus, hendrerit et fermentum a, 
  sagittis at lorem. Proin at pellentesque massa. Suspendisse potenti.
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class = "col-1-3">
     <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mattis 
  ultrices sem vitae suscipit. Donec sollicitudin lacus ac nisl fermentum 
  eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et 
  malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur leo leo, aliquet at varius nec, 
  laoreet efficitur ligula. Fusce at lacinia tortor. Interdum et malesuada 
  fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus scelerisque justo id 
  interdum placerat. Aenean tincidunt tellus ac eros viverra rhoncus. Nam 
  vitae sollicitudin magna. Praesent neque tellus, hendrerit et fermentum a, 
  sagittis at lorem. Proin at pellentesque massa. Suspendisse potenti.
     </p>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class = "footer">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand what you need. If all you need is the content to go over the footer, this should do:

**UPDATED**

First you need to clear the grid from it's floating children, so you can add as padding-bottom as needed.

```
.grid {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I intend to put social media icons in the footer eventually, so having the content display over it is not what really what I am looking for. I would like the containers that have the text in to ensure all of the text and content is visible above the footer. 

Currently, if you view it in mobile view you can see the last line of text is being obscured by the footer. 

P.S I will make sure I do that in future!

Comment: Then, why is a problem that the content goes behind the footer? I definetly don't understand what you need

Comment: sorry if I am being unclear when you scroll to the bottom of the page in any view other than the desktop, the last line of text is obscured by the footer even when you have scrolled as far as you can go.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. I just updated the solution, try it

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, please can I ask exactly what content:""; doing?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Here's an extensive explanation about it https://www.fuseinteractive.ca/blog/understanding-humble-clearfix